# Room IllegalArgumentException: intcannot be converted to an Element

Tags: java, android, android-room

I'm having this error when trying to compile the project:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: intcannot be converted to an Element

And this warning:

> Warning:Supported source version 'RELEASE_7' from annotation processor 'android.arch.persistence.room.RoomProcessor' less than -source '1.8'

These are my database related classes:

```
@Entity(tableName = "users")
public class SerializedUser {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "username")
    private String username;

    public SerializedUser(int id, String firstName, String lastName, String username) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }
}

@android.arch.persistence.room.Database(entities = {SerializedUser.class}, version = 4)
public abstract class Database extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract UserDao userDao();

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "weather";

    // For Singleton instantiation
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();
    private static volatile Database i;

    public static Database init(Context context) {
        if (i == null) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                if (i == null) {
                    i = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            Database.class, Database.DATABASE_NAME)
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration().build();
                }
            }
        }
        return i;
    }

    public static boolean isInited(){
        return i != null;
    }

    public static Database getInstance(){
        if(i == null)
            throw new NullPointerException("Database.getInstance called when Database not initialized");
        return i;
    }
}

@Dao
public abstract class UserDao {

    Converters converters;

    public void inject(Converters converters) {
        this.converters = converters;
    }

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    public abstract void saveNow(SerializedUser user);

    @Delete
    public abstract void deleteNow(int id);

    @Query("DELETE FROM users")
    public abstract void deleteAllNow();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM users")
    public abstract List<SerializedUser> getAllNow();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY last_name ASC")
    public abstract LivePagedListProvider<Integer, SerializedUser> usersByLastName();
}
```

So the error happens when it tries to implement the database classes? That id on SerializedUser is not the problem, I have commented it out, the problem was still the same. Tried to clean and rebuild the project and restarted Android Studio (invalidate and restart).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

remove

```
@Delete
public abstract void deleteNow(int id);
```

from your Dao it will work

Comment: A little explanation would be good, gonna try if this solve my issue or not but I still don't understand why. Would be nice if you include why I should remove this.

Comment: you can delete an Entity not an id you can write query to delete user by ID . Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538857/android-room-delete-with-parameters?rq=1

Comment: To use the `@Delete` annotation you need to provide a Room Entity. You can use `@Query` if you want to delete an Entity using the `id` like:
`@Query("DELETE FROM clothes WHERE id = :Id") public abstract void deleteById(int id)`

Comment: The same applies to `@Insert` annotated methods: the argument must be an entity.

Answer (score 9):

> `@Delete` annotation marks a method in a Dao annotated class as a
>   delete method. The implementation of the method will delete its
>   parameters from the database.
>   **All** of the parameters of the Delete method must either be classes annotated with `Entity` or collections/array of it.

Read [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Delete.html) for extra information.

So in your case you pass a parameter with `int` type which violates the aforementioned rule. That is why you are getting that error.

In order to resolve this issue, you should either exclude `deleteNow` method or just pass any parameter that does not violates the rule that was mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: intcannot be converted to an Element

Basically, this problem arises not only by the `@Delete` query, but by all the Room's CRUD annotations (`@Insert`, `@Delete`, `@Update`) except `@Query`.

All of the parameters of these CRUD annotated methods must either be classes annotated with Entity or collections/array of it.

So we can't pass primitive or other than these.