# Android Room @Delete with parameters

Tags: java, android, sql, android-room

I know I can't use `DELETE` in a query (that is a shame by the way), I will get the following error:

```
<i>Error:error: Observable query return type (LiveData, Flowable etc) can only be used with SELECT queries that directly or indirectly (via @Relation, for example) access at least one table.</i>
```

But I can't use `@Delete(WHERE... xxx)`
So how do I delete a specific row by a parameter?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The beauty of room is, we play with the objects. As per requirement you can use 
for kotlin:

```
@Delete
fun delete(model: LanguageModel)
```

for Java:

```
@Delete
void delete(LanguageModel model)
```

it will delete the exact object which is stored in the db with the same values. LanguageModel is my model class and it works perfectly.

Comment: Just a minor observation: [The documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#convenience-delete) only mentions matching on primary keys for `@Delete` annotated methods. It is a bit unclear what will happen if there is no primary key definition in the model.

Comment: If it were to "delete the exact object which is stored in the db with the same values", it would be useless, because objects change in the DB, and deleting them later on shouldn't require me to know their exact data; I only need to know the primary key.

Comment: @dbm atleast one primary key is required in an Entity in roomdb

Comment: @AndroidLearner that's actually a valid point. Shortcut to documentation for future visitors: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data

Comment: That's not the beauty, that's a hassle if you know the id to delete but don't want to fetch the whole object

Comment: @zaitsman The documentation says "*Room uses the primary key to match passed entity instances to rows in the database.*". This seems to imply that you don't need to load the stored object, but you could also just create a new instance and fill its primary key fields. In this case, it's not quite "*the exact object which is stored*"

Answer (score 351):

Actually, you can use `@Query` to perform a delete.

```
@Query("DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = :userId")
abstract void deleteByUserId(long userId);
```

Extracted from [Query javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Query.html):

> UPDATE or DELETE queries can return void or int. If it is an int, the
>   value is the number of rows affected by this query.

Comment: this works, I've been using something like this and *delete all* is written this way too.

for reference check this: (https://stackoverflow.com/a/44249498/2185548)

Comment: @Delete doesn't work for me for some reason. But this works!

Comment: @Rakesh You might be having an autogenerated primary id in your entity, which means you can only delete is using some parameter, like "userId" here.

Comment: Thanks for the information @Maragues. the "UPDATE or DELETE queries can return void or int. If it is an int, the value is the number of rows affected by this query." stuff is what I was looking for. it worked for me.

Answer (score 49):

You can use below method to delete by ID

```
@Query("DELETE FROM yourDatabaseTable WHERE id = :id")
void deleteById(int id);
```

for delete all rows

```
@Query("DELETE FROM yourDatabaseTable")
void delete();
```

Comment: Hi! Using second method to delete the database, is it possible to return a value (true or false) whether the deletion is successfully done or note? Thanks!

Comment: @MarkDelphi If `delete` operation was successful, it would return number of rows that have been deleted. So a return of `-1` implies operation failed.

Answer (score 6):

ROOM database provides easy way to INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE an object in the database. To perform thus operation just needed to annotate @Delete. The **DELETE operation returns the Int** when deletion of the single object is successful returns 1 else returns 0 if the DELETE operation is unsuccessful, Adding the return type is a good practice.

**KotlinEG.kt**

```
   @Dao
   interface EntityLocalDAO {
       @Delete
       fun deleteData(entityObject: EntityObject) : Int
   }
```

**javaEG.java**

```
   @Dao
   interface EntityLocalDAO {
       @Delete
       int deleteData(EntityObject entityObject);
   }
```

Comment: Does Insert and Update returns int as well?

Comment: Insert return Long value :)

Comment: Insert return is the inserted row's id

Comment: A good point anyway, but this does not answer the question of the OP! For a newer and clean way to "delete with a parameter", see the answer by @Randy (https://stackoverflow.com/a/72356339/2350638)

Answer (score 4):

You can now delete using only partial data.

Per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/room/Delete?hl=en):

```
@Entity
data class Playlist (
    @PrimaryKey
    val playlistId: Long,
    val ownerId: Long,
    val name: String,
    @ColumnInfo(defaultValue = "normal")
    val category: String
)

data class OwnerIdAndCategory (
    val ownerId: Long,
    val category: String
)

@Dao
public interface PlaylistDao {
    @Delete(entity = Playlist::class)
    fun deleteByOwnerIdAndCategory(varargs idCategory: OwnerIdAndCategory)
}
```

In this example you can see that they are deleting the Playlist using only the ownerId and the category. You do not even need to use the primary key (playlistId).

The key is to use the @Delete(entity = Playlist::class) annotation.