# How to get a callback when room completed deleting or adding of item?

Tags: android, android-room

I want to send a request right after Room finished deleting or adding some item/items. To a database I use room + livedata, but for add/delete item I use doAsync. How I can get a callback when item deleting/adding is completed?

Examples for add/delete and get in my database

```
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
fun saveUser(user: SavedUserModel)

@Query("SELECT * FROM SavedUserModel")
fun getUser(): List<SavedUserModel>

@Query("DELETE FROM SavedShoppingListModel WHERE id LIKE :id")
fun deleteById(id: String)
```

Comment: "I use doAsync" -- what do you mean by this? Since you are in Kotlin, you could switch to coroutines and have these be `suspend` functions. With coroutines, you would no longer need a callback, as you find out when the work is done when those `suspend` functions return.

Comment: @CommonsWare he just wants to check if the query executes till the end I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return an `Int` from delete or update. The value will be the number of affected rows. Once `return` is called by simple programing you know that execution of the method has finished. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47538857/android-room-delete-with-parameters) thread for more, most voted answer.

Or, you can use [Room + RxJava](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757) and return a `Completable` and look for the on completion state in the `onComplete` method. This one is sweeter solution IMO. But the first solution also would work, I guess.

I think that if you also return `LiveData<List<T>>` from the selection query, your delete would be able to be detected from room. Not really sure for this last one.

EDIT: As @CommonsWare mentioned in comments, you another option is coroutines. Mark methods as `suspend`ed and then go to paragraph 1 of this answer.

Comment: Thanks, Int return helped. Yep, I know about RX and Coroutines, but it's a legacy code from previous team and for now there is no time or money for rewrite

Comment: Well, there is always time to do it better. But anw, glad I helped. GL