# How to delete an object from sqlite db with condition of his attribute in Android Room

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite, android-room

I want to delete a row (object) from my `SQLite db` if the attribute `lessonId` match with one of the object in my `db`.
I'm using `Room`.

I don't know which Query I should put.

NotificationDao:

```
@Dao
interface NotificationDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM notifications")
    fun getNotifications(): Single<List<Notification>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun updateNotification(notification: Notification): Completable

    @Query("DELETE")
    fun clearNotification(notification: Notification): Completable
}
```

Notification class:

```
@Entity(tableName = "notifications")
data class Notification(
        @PrimaryKey
        var lessonId: String = "",
        var count: Int = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use Delete with condition (but you have to change parameter's type)?

```
@Query("DELETE FROM notifications WHERE lessonId = :lessonId")
fun clearNotification(lessonId: String): Completable
```

Comment: indeed I found this answer yesterday:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/47554641/7937498